# How to Center Text in FPDF?

Tags: php, pdf-generation, fpdf

How can I have this generated text appear centered in the page.

Generated = `$_POST` method ... so I don't know how long will the text in input be.  I need to have a pre-determined center parameter somehow.

Any ideas?  Maybe like this:

```
MultiCell(0,$height,"text",0,'C') ?
```

Answer (score 16):

Normally it's  `$pdf->Cell(0, $height, "text", 0, 0, 'C');` but if you're doing it in a Header or Footer function it's `$this->Cell(0, $height, "text", 0, 0, 'C')`. Don't forget to declare `$height` as a global if you're doing this in a function() call.

Answer (score 6):

Thanks taur! This works for me:

```
$mid_x = 135; // the middle of the "PDF screen", fixed by now.
$text = $userFullName;
$pdf_file->Text($mid_x - ($pdf_file->GetStringWidth($text) / 2), 102, $text);
```

Comment: You can calculate the center of the document: `$mid_x = $pdf_file->w / 2;`

Answer (score 3):

This may work for you

```
MultiCell(0,$height,'You can<P ALIGN="center">center a line</P>',0,'C')
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Rather than only post a block of code, please explain why this code solves the problem posed. Without an explanation, this is not an answer.

Comment: @Artemix is right, you should explain the code. Nevertheless, it worked perfect for me.

Answer (score 2):

```
$pdf->Text($mid_x-$pdf->GetStringWidth($text)/2,$y,$text);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
            global $title;

            
            // Calculate width of text and position
            $w = $this->GetStringWidth($title)+6;
            $this->SetX((210-$w)/2);
            
        
            // Line break
            $this->Ln(10);

         
            $title = 'YOUR TEXT HERE';
            $this->SetTitle($title);
            $this->SetTextColor(0,0, 0);
            $this->SetFont('Arial','',17);
            $this->SetX(((210-$w)/4),(-50));
            $this->Cell(10, 20, $title);
```

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me

```
$mid_x = $pdf->GetPageWidth() / 2;
$text = $userName;
$pdf->Text($mid_x - ($pdf->GetStringWidth($text) / 2),{height}, $text);
```